# If a '-' contain in int input it will print something

Tags: python, input, integer

well what im trying to do its when you input a "-Number"
it will print something

and this the error im getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    if "-" in use:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

this is my code

```
n1 = 800
use = []
use2 = []

while use != n1:
  use = int(input("Money: "))
  use2.append(use)
  print("The money that left:",800 - sum(use2))

  if "-" in use:
    print('ok')
```

Comment: you convert input to an integer and you can't check if a string is in an integer, did you mean to check if the value is negative? then just `if use < 0:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n1 = 800
use = []
use2 = []

while use != n1:
  use = input("Money: ")
  use2.append(int(use))
  print("The money that left:",800 - sum(use2))

  if "-" in use:
    print('ok')
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The line `if "-" in use` attemps to see if the character `"-"` is contained in the `use` variable by iterating over it's characters, and that would work if the `use` variable was a string, but since integers aren't iterable, an error occurs. Just check if the `use` variable is below zero, since all negative integers have a - in front of them. This should work for you:

```
n1 = 800
use = []
use2 = []

while use != n1:
  use = int(input("Money: "))
  use2.append(use)
  print("The money that left:",800 - sum(use2))

  if use < 0:
      print('ok')
```